# You have a 64-bit number 0xCCCCCCCCAAAAAAAA. Write an assembly program to implement 64-bit Logic Shift Right. Shift this 64-bit number right by 4

Tags: assembly, arm

Q: You have a 64-bit number 0xCCCCCCCCAAAAAAAA. Write an assembly program to implement 64-bit Logic Shift Right. Shift this 64-bit number right by 4.

```
LDR R0, =0xCCCCCCCC
LDR R1, =0xAAAAAAAA
LSR R2, R0, #2
LSR R3, R1, #2
```

Does shifting each 32 bit segment by 2 equate to shifting the 64 bit number by 4?

Comment: No, it is not the same thing.

Comment: A C compiler can show you how to do this, for `return x>>4;` on uint64_t x.  https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hello Sami! Is it possible for you to explain how I may correct my code? I'm very stuck on this at the moment.

Comment: Use a calculator to compute the answer, and make sure your code sequence gets the proper answer.  FYI, the 64-bit answer is 0x0CCCCCCCAAAAAAA, so in 2 32-bit halves: 0x0CCCCCCC, 0xCAAAAAAA.  You must shift by 4, and to work the two parts together: 4 low bits from the high order move to the high bits of the low order.  You're shifting by 2 and not moving one of the 0xC's to the other.  Use godbolt as Peter says, arch=arm7-a (clang) and option -O3 will show you what the compiler does.

Comment: which arm instruction set are you going after?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long fun ( unsigned long long x )
{
    return(x>>4);
}
```

This is the most obvious one the one you would use if doing it in C

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1a00220    lsr r0, r0, #4
   4:   e1800e01    orr r0, r0, r1, lsl #28
   8:   e1a01221    lsr r1, r1, #4
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

But there are these as well, all being ARM

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   070b        lsls    r3, r1, #28
   2:   0900        lsrs    r0, r0, #4
   4:   4318        orrs    r0, r3
   6:   0909        lsrs    r1, r1, #4
   8:   4770        bx  lr

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0900        lsrs    r0, r0, #4
   2:   ea40 7001   orr.w   r0, r0, r1, lsl #28
   6:   0909        lsrs    r1, r1, #4
   8:   4770        bx  lr

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   d344fc00    lsr x0, x0, #4
   4:   d65f03c0    ret
```

And naturally you fill in the constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
movw    r0, #0xaaaa
movw    r1, #0xcccc
movt    r0, #0xaaaa
movt    r1, #0xcccc

lsr     r2, r0, #4
lsr     r3, r1, #4
bfi     r2, r1, #28, #4
```

Comment: That's even simpler than using lookup table...

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It depends on the level of the OP. This one doesn't need an explanation but a complete tutorial consisting of multiple chapters: Ch1. Two's complement; Ch2. ARM instruction encoding; Ch3. Barrel Shifter; Ch4. 64 bit integers on 32bit systems; Ch5. Pipelines; Ch6. Dependencies; Ch7. ARM instruction cycle timing; I won't do this - at least not for free.